# Oracle select mutual sub string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, group-by, substring

I would like to return new table in ORACLE where all rows that
have same the values in 'col' columns group together
and the 'description' column will contain only the mutual sub strings
when the different characters will replaced by '...'

how can I do that? May i get your help please?

Basic code to start with:
SELECT col,description
FROM table
group by col;

**Example 1:**

```
col description
1   Today is 
1   Today is a good day
1   Today is perfect day
2   Hello world
2   Hello
```

*results:*

```
col description
1   Today is …
2   Hello…
```

**Example 2:**

```
col description
1   Today is a good day
1   Today is perfect day
2   Hello world
2   Hello I'm here
3   Hi
```

*results:*

```
col description
1   Today is …
2   Hello…
3   Hi
```

thanks!

Comment: So you want to find the longest common substring?  Can you articulate the logic here?

Comment: What would you do with "Today is a good day to say Hello World?" :-)

Comment: Hi Tim, yes. i want to find the longest.

Comment: Hi Tony,
 i want to look on the string from the first letter. so if i have the string: "Today is a good day to say Hello World" i want to return "today is.."

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You can use `not exists`:

```
select col, description || ' ...'
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.description like t.description || '%' and
                        t2.descriptoin <> t.description
                 );
```

Note that on a large table, this will not be efficient!

Comment: thank you Linorff. Could you look on my second example please?

Comment: @MaayanPaz-Chen . . . This answers the original version of the question.  You changed the question . . . you should ask a *new* question rather than invalidating this answer.

Comment: I'm sorry , I chose bad example. this is a link to new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62756449/oracle-select-mutual-sub-string-from-different-rows