# Oracle select mutual sub string from different rows

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substring

I would like to return new table in ORACLE where all the rows that have same  values in 'col' column group together and the 'description' column will contain only the mutual sub strings when the different characters will replaced by '...'

How can I do that? May I get your help please?

**Example:**

```
col description
1   Today is a good day
1   Today is perfect day
2   Hello world
2   Hello I'm here
3   Hi
```

*Result:*

```
col description
1   Today is …
2   Hello…
3   Hi
```

thanks!

Comment: I have seen exactly this post earlier today. What happened to the older one?Is it deleted or what?[**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62754557/oracle-select-mutual-sub-string) is the post. Please ask your further doubts there itself rather than opening another post.

Comment: Hi Mandy, I chose bad example in my last post, so i posting it again as one of the users asked me. this is the link to the original post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62754557/oracle-select-mutual-sub-string

Comment: You can edit there only no issues; until and unless you have accepted the answer and after that trying to re-edit.

Comment: yes i did that and therefore added:"example 2" but someone told that it's a different question now

Comment: @Mandy8055 . . . This is *not* the same.  The data is quite different, because the results need to be imputed.  SQL is not the right tool for this.

Comment: @MaayanPaz-Chen . . . And why isn't the answer just "H" for the last two?  This is not a problem that is readily solved in SQL (possible but it is the wrong tool).

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff  first of all- thank you. i need to group by col. so for the value '3' there aren't other rows to compare with. i compare between all the values that have the same value in 'col' (1,2,3).  For example: for the value '2' i compare 'hello word' and 'hello I'm here' , then need to find when the string changed and take only the substring (starting from the first index) that is mutual to their both. in this case is:"hello" so in my output table i have row that contain 2 and hello

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want, first you will need to know how common string start can be found in Oracle:

```
with rws as ( 
  -- generate rows up to the length of the longest string 
  select rownum r from dual 
  connect by level <= (select max(length(str)) from strings) 
) 
select distinct s  
from ( 
  select str, max(subp) s  
  from ( 
    select str,  
           substr(str, 1, rws.r) subp 
    from   strings s1 
    cross join rws 
    where  r < length(str) 
    and    exists ( 
      -- check whether there's another string matching the first N chars 
      select * from strings s2 
      where  s1.str <> s2.str 
      and    substr(s1.str, 1, rws.r) = substr(s2.str, 1, rws.r) 
    ) 
  )  
  group by str 
)
```

Taken from https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CC83ZWPCPESEDTADIFOSB1EXI.html

Of course, you will need to apply this to your table. Differences:

- you will need to use your columns
- you will need to group by col